# How to bind a RabbitListener to multiple routing keys on the same exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

How can I bind a Rabbit Listener to multiple routing keys on the same exchange? I am using spring-rabbit 1.7.9.RELEASE.

This is what I have so far:

```
@RabbitListener(bindings = {
    @QueueBinding(value =
        @Queue(value = "foo"), exchange = @Exchange("ex1"), key="foo")
})
public void listen(String in) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `key` attribute of that `@QueueBinding` annotation is like this:

```
/**
 * @return the routing key or pattern for the binding.
 * Multiple elements will result in multiple bindings.
 */
String[] key() default {};
```

So, you just need to have a list of those routing keys:

```
@QueueBinding(value =
    @Queue(value = "foo"), exchange = @Exchange("ex1"), key={"foo", "bar", "baz"})
```

Or pattern as you see from those JavaDocs.

Comment: That does not work for me. I am using spring-rabbit 1.7.9.RELEASE. Its impl is `String key() default "";
`

Comment: Well, you must mention that in the question then not making a confuse for us. So, declare another `@RabbitListener` method then! Or just upgrade to more modern version of the library...